# Почему не находит слово в регулярном выражении?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Пример: https://regex101.com/r/JXpUwE/1

Регулярка `<strong>\w<\/strong>`

Текст:

```
<strong>слово</strong>
<strong>word</strong>
<strong>два слова</strong>
```

Он же вроде бы должен найти строки внутри которых есть слово. Почему этого не происходит? То же самое, он вроде должен найти совпадения на "не пробел" `<strong>\S<\/strong>` но не находит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что шаблону \w соответствует только один символ. Напишите \w+ или \w* например.